# Installing imagemagick on user account

Tags: software-installation, imagemagick

The version of ImageMagick on the machine I am using is too old for the operation I am trying to execute. I do not have admin privileges and the sysadmin will not upgrade ImageMagick.

How do I install a newer version of ImageMagick on my own account?

The process I tried was as follows:

```
$ wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-6.8.8-10/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make PREFIX=/home/josh/bin install
make  install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
Making install in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la wand/libMagickWand-6.Q16.la Magick++/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c magick/.libs/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/josh/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have to use the `DESTDIR` environment variable to tell `make` to install **ImageMagick** into your `$HOME` directory:

```
DESTDIR=/home/josh/ImageMagick make install
```

Installation is done but there is one final step to do because by default all **ImageMagick** binaries will look for libraries in system-wide paths, giving this sort of errors:

```
./convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To work around this problem, just prefix the call to one of the **ImageMagick** program with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/josh/ImageMagick/usr/local/lib/`, like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/josh/ImageMagick/usr/local/lib/ /home/josh/ImageMagick/usr/local/bin/convert -h
```